# When render a JS component in native UIView, the OnPress doesn't work

Tags: react-native

The scenario is:

JS -> Objective-C -> JS

Generally, i want to embed a JS component in a native UIView, and the JS view should respond to user interaction events, such as onPress event.

Details:
In my JS component, i called the IOS native method like this:

```
var CategoryManager = NativeModules.CategoryManager;
CategoryManager.showCategoryPopup();
```

in the showCategoryPopup() objective-c method, i create a uiview, and add a subview to the parent uiview, the subview is created from the JS component using the RCTRootView class:

```
UIView *parentView = [UIView new];
RCTRootView *subview_1 = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:[[RCCManager sharedIntance] getBridge] moduleName:@"CategoryViewPopup" initialProperties:nil];
[parentView addSubview: subview_1];
```

here the `CategoryViewPopup` is a JS component:

```
export default class CategoryViewPopup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textToggle: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleText.bind(this)}>
        <View style={{width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
          <Text>{this.state.textToggle ? "Text 1" : "Text 2"}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  toggleText() {
    this.setState({
      textToggle: !this.state.textToggle,
    });
  }
}
```

But the `onPress` event doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class CategoryViewPopup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      textToggle: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleText.bind(this)}>
        <View style={{width: 100, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
          <Text>{this.state.textToggle ? "Text 1" : "Text 2"}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  toggleText() {
    this.setState({
      textToggle: !this.state.textToggle,
    });
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    flex : 1,
    backgroundColor : 'rgba(244,244,244,0.9)',
    justifyContent : 'center',
    alignItems : 'center'
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not a style issue, and i have tested your code, it doesn't work either. thanks!

Comment: even I have tested and on press it was changing the text Text2 to Text1 and vice versa...

Comment: Did you test it with embed the CategoryViewPopup component into a UIView or just directly render the CategoryViewPopup in a JS component?

Comment: If you render the CategoryViewPopup directly in the JS component, i know it will work obviously, but what i want is embed CategoryViewPopup into a UIView and the CategoryViewPopup should accept the user interaction event (onPress) as well, but which is not working as a result.

Comment: @rockllei I think i can help you in that you can add me on Skype which is rajeev.upadhyay72 so that i can give you solution!!!
coz i m professionally iOS developer also working on reactNative.